# Using OData with breeze - query not executed

Tags: breeze

i am trying to query webapi asp.net odata controller using breeze
in my query

```
    function getIncidentsInternal() {
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("Customers");

        //var serverAddress = "http://localhost:53809/odata/";
        var serverAddress = "/odata";
        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serverAddress);

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(getSucceededInternal); // caller to handle failure
```

after the metadata request there is no actual request to get the items
i see one error of

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:53809/odata/$metadata 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

after this request there is a GEt request with the metadata which pass but no query

Comment: Did you resolve this, I have same problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you got a 405, I bet you have issues with CORS. Does you OData service support CORS? Also, looks like you need to change breeze to use OData instead of web api. you can do that like so..

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
```